# Javascript detect if hover is on bottom or top padding of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I know it might sound like a weird question but I have some items in a list with the following HTML:

```
<div class="list-cards">
    <div class="list-item">
        <a class="list-card" draggable="true">item</a>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <a class="list-card" draggable="true">item</a>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <a class="list-card" draggable="true">item</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.list-item {
  padding: 4px 0px;
}
```

.list-cards = my list
.list-item = 1 list-item
.list-card = simply the style and text of an item (not important for this question)

Now I want to detect whether, when hovering, I'm hovering on the padding-top of my list-item div or on the padding-bottom. 
(maybe there is a way to get the full height of my item and then use some kind of mouse coordinate to know my 'height' (=position of mouse)? If there is then I have no idea how to do this

**For backstory**: 
I'm making some kind of drag & drop to-do list as a project. I can drag my items between x amount of lists but I always just append the item to the bottom of the list.
 Now I want to use the padding of my list-item to check if I'm above or below an item
If I know that I can add the item that I'm dragging around either above or below an item depending on where I released my mouse button

I would prefer a solution using vanilla javascript but if jQuery is required then that's fine too. Other frameworks/libraries I'd prefer not to touch

Once again, thanks in advance

Comment: You could check what the x and y values are when the element is being and determine if it is the top or bottom padding...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like the following, adapt to your code as needed

it takes the offset of the target element and compares that to the location of the event. If the event is in the top half of the target element it records above, else below.

```
$('.list-item').hover(function(e) {
  var offset = $(this).offset().top;
  var this_height = $(this).height();
  var Y = e.pageY;
  var loc = Math.abs(offset - Y);
  if (loc < this_height/2) {
    console.log('above');
  }
  else {
    console.log('below');
  }

})
```